# Related to feed Items

Tags: salesforce-id, feeditem

Here I am uploading data From Audit trail to Feed Items through a trigger ,but during inserting records in Feed Items Trigger Throwing error like "Entity is not api accessible" this,can anyone give solutions to fix this error.

Comment: Please post some more details and if possible code snippet also.

Comment: Mr.Saroj I have posted the code can u please check that whats error in that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure chatter is enabled in your organization.